# Join wide table from different starting dates

Tags: r, date, join, merge

Hey guys I have 2 DBs:

**BaseDB**:

*"id"*, *"Main_event_date"*

```
*id*  *Main_event_date*
1       01/01/2017
2       01/07/2018
3       01/11/2017
```

**DB_2**

*"id"*,*"event_date"*

```
*id*   *event_date*
1       01/02/2017
1       19/12/2017
1       19/01/2018
2       01/10/2018
2       10/01/2019
```

DB_2 might be duplicated in "id": every time an "id" has an event, I have a new row with a new "event_date".

I reshaped the DB_2 from long to wide using "reshape", so that now I have:
**DB_2_wide**

*"id"*, *"event_date0"*, *"event_date1"*....*"event_date100"*.

I would like to join the BaseDB with DB_2_Wide considering only the first 30 events after the *main_event_date* for every *"id"* having a final table of the type:

**Final_Table**

*id*, *t1*, ... *t30*

```
*id* *t1* *t2* *t3*   ..... *t30*
1      x   NA    NA
2      NA  NA    x
3      NA  NA    NA


Considering also that t1 for 1 is Feb2017, 
                      t1 for 2 is August 2018
                      t1 for 3 is December 2017
```

Not sure how to do this because simply using *left_join* *(or merge)* I would get a table like:

*"id"*, *"event_date0"*, *"event_date1"*....*"event_date100"*,

hence for every *id* I would also get a column for *events* before the *main_event_date*, which would be *NA*.

Not sure this is clear so let me know if have any questions.

Comment: Welcome! This is not clear. Could you edit your question to provide reproducible sample data of the two databases, and the desired final output?

Comment: Hi Roberto, welcome to SO! It’ll be much easier to help if we have a copy-pasteable sample of your data. The easiest way to provide this is running `dput(head(BaseDB, 10))` and pasting the result into your question, and the same for `DB_2`. See [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/17303805) for more info. Thanks!

Comment: What I am thinking is that I could do a wide-type table having 
*id*, *Main_event_date*, *t1*....*t30*,
and then fill the cells based on 
*tx*=*event_date* 
for every *id*.

I don't exactly know how to code this but it might work...